# How can I pad a background image from the element edge?

Tags: html, css, padding

I want to add a background image on the right side of the list items, and want to have some padding from the right side as well, but I'm unable to do that. Please have a look at following example:

I know we can set the image position by pixels, but since each of the li has different width, I can't do that.

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/50") no-repeat center right;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: yellow url("https://via.placeholder.com/50") no-repeat center right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello world</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use percent values for the `background-position` property:

```
background: yellow url("arrow1.gif") no-repeat 95% 50%;
```

Not pixel perfect, but…

Answer (score 241):

You can be more precise with [CSS background-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin):

```
background-origin: content-box;
```

This will make image respect the padding of the box.

Comment: Doesn't this offset the top left of the background to inside the padding, but still go outside the padding in the bottom right? The `background-clip` answer seems better.

Comment: This does not make the image respect the box padding on all 4 sides. It only repositions the image relative to the `background-position`. For example, if the padding is 5px and the image position is `center left`, this will move the image 5px from the left. It will not resize or crop the image by 5px on the top, bottom or right.

Comment: @mikemaccana @Jargs you will need to combine both `background-origin` and `background-clip` in some cases where you want the background to be resized to fit the content-box but then _also_ cropped to fit the content-box as well. The first one does the resizing, while the second does the cropping.

Comment: @mikemaccana To fix the image extending past the bottom/right border, you have to combine the `background-origin: content-box;` with `background-size: contain;` (or other similar size-constraining options).

Answer (score 23):

Use [CSS background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip):

```
background-clip: content-box;
```

The background will be painted within the content box.

Comment: it will 'crop' the image when using with things like `background-size: contain;`

Comment: This works but it crops the background colour too

Comment: I wanted to crop the background-color, so this is perfect for me.

Answer (score 11):

Use `background-position: calc(100% - 20px) center`, For pixel perfection `calc()` is the best solution.

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: url("https://placehold.co/200x125/e16d65/FFFFFF/png") no-repeat calc(100% - 10px) center;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-position: calc(100% - 20px) center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello world</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is nice if you want custom padding for background. Ex.: `background-position: 5px 10px; background-size: calc(100%-10px) calc(100%-20px);`

Comment: @Steffan "The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace", so `background-size: calc(100% - 10px) calc(100% - 20px)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678942/does-calc-work-for-background-size-of-image-in-css/30679082#30679082

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your results with two methods:-

***First Method*** define **position values**:-

**HTML**

```
 <ul>
 <li>Hello</li>
 <li>Hello world</li>
 </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
    ul{
    width:100px;    
}

ul li{
    border:1px solid orange;
    background: url("http://www.adaweb.net/Portals/0/Images/arrow1.gif") no-repeat 90% 5px;
}


ul li:hover{
    background: yellow url("http://www.adaweb.net/Portals/0/Images/arrow1.gif") no-repeat 90% 5px;
}
```

**First Demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/QeGAd/18/

***Second Method*** by CSS **:before:after** Selectors

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Hello world</li>
```

**CSS**

```
    ul{
    width:100px;    
}

ul li{
    border:1px solid orange;
}

ul li:after {
    content: " ";
    padding-right: 16px;
    background: url("http://www.adaweb.net/Portals/0/Images/arrow1.gif") no-repeat center right;
}

ul li:hover {
    background:yellow;
}

ul li:hover:after {
    content: " ";
    padding-right: 16px;
    background: url("http://www.adaweb.net/Portals/0/Images/arrow1.gif") no-repeat center right;
}
```

**Second Demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/QeGAd/17/

Answer (score 3):

You can just add the padding to tour block element and add `background-origin` style like so:

```
.block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-image: url(_your_image_);
  height: 14rem;
  width: 10rem;
}
```

You can check several https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-origin.asp

Answer (score 1):

The only option to actuall have this made pixel perfect is to create some transparent padding within the GIF itself. That way you can actually align it to the right of the LI and still have the background padding you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `box-sizing: content-box` seems to also work. Note that you may have to adjust the `height`, `width`, and `background-size` to account for padding with this method.

Comment: Could you provide a working code example?

Answer (score -1):

setting [direction](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp) CSS property to rtl should work with you. I guess it isn't supported on IE6.

e.g

```
<ul style="direction:rtl;">
<li> item </li>
<li> item </li>
</ul>
```