# Does calc() work for background size of image in CSS?

Tags: css, background, calc

My question is very simple, does `calc()` work for background size of a background image in pure CSS...

Right now I am fixing a background image for responsive mobile view...
I want the image to stay fixed in ratio of the screen but resize on any mobile screen...

I implemented this code, it's not working currently:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
   body { 
      background-size: calc(100%-200px) auto; 
      background-repeat: repeat; 
   }    
}
```

Is it possible in pure CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the CSS calc() function work for me in IE9 and Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108285/why-doesnt-the-css-calc-function-work-for-me-in-ie9-and-safari)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it does work everwhere you could otherwise put numbers with units like %, em, rem, px, cm, vh etc.

I ran in to this as well: You **must** put a space before and after the `-`:

```
calc(100% - 200px)
```

I asked something similar here: [Why is CSS calc(100%-250px) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412580/why-is-css-calc100-250px-not-working)

**From the MDN docs:**

> Note: The `+` and `-` operators must always be surrounded by whitespace.
>   The operand of `calc(50% -8px)` for instance will be parsed as a
>   percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while
>   the operand of `calc(50% - 8px)` is a percentage followed by a minus
>   sign and a length. Even further, `calc(8px + -50%)` is treated as a
>   length followed by a plus sign and a negative percentage. The `*` and `/`
>   operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is
>   allowed, and recommended.
>
> Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

[W3C Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc)